# Laravel 5.2 Array to string conversion error form

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

My working project simple form, but I get the error:

> ErrorException in 350957ec60e1dd25a26f206394651974bb23e6b7.php line
>   40: Array to string conversion (View:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\laravelku\resources\views\siswa\edit.blade.php)

and this my code:

```
@extends('template')

@section('main')
    <div id="siswa">
        <h2>Edit Siswa</h2>

        {!! Form::model($siswa,['method' => 'PATCH', 'action' => ['SiswaController@update', $siswa->id]]) !!}
        <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('nisn', 'NISN:', ['class' => 'control-label']) !!}
            {!! Form::text('nisn', null,['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
        </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                {!! Form::label('nama_siswa','Nama:',['class' => 'control-label']) !!}
                {!! Form::text('nama_siswa',null,['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
            </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('tanggal_lahir','Tanggal Lahir:',['class' => 'control-label']) !!}
            {!! Form::date('tanggal_lahir',null,['class' => 'form-control','id' => 'tanggal_lahir']) !!}
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('jenis_kelamin','Jenis Kelamin:', ['class' => 'control-label']) !!}
            <div class="radio">
                <label>{!! Form::radio('jenis_kelamin', 'L') !!} Laki-laki</label>
            </div>
            <div class="radio">
                <label>{!! Form::radio('jenis_kelamin','P') !!} Perempuan</label>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::submit('Update Siswa'), ['class' => 'btn btn-primary form-control'] !!}
        </div>
        {!! Form::close() !!}
    </div>
    @stop

    @section('footer')
        @include('footer')
    @stop
```

Answer (score 1):

The `Form::submit()` syntax is wrong. Change this:

```
{!! Form::submit('Update Siswa'), ['class' => 'btn btn-primary form-control'] !!}
```

To this:

```
{!! Form::submit('Update Siswa', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary form-control']) !!}
```